# Got Twice trigger on change paste keyup

Tags: php, jquery

So i have scanner and input text, if scanner get value max 9 digit, is will insert ot my database (automacly). These my coding

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $( "#scannerinput" ).focus();
        $('#scannerinput').bind("change paste keyup", function(){
            var barcode = $(this).val();
            var judul = $(this).attr("target-judul");
            var dataString = "judul=" + judul + "&barcode=" + barcode;
            if(this.value.length ==9){
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url+"ajax",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        //window.location.href = url;
                    }
                });

                $( "#scannerinput" ).blur(); 
                //console.log(dataString);
            }
        });
    });
```

My problem is my code make insert twice or get trigger twice. How to make it just once trigger??? Any idea??

Comment: Use only `change` event

Comment: @Satpal : omg, how i'm became silly. Tq for that!!! your helping me :)
Prob u can answer my question post and i will approve that your answer :)

Comment: and also change this if(this.value.length ==9) to if(this.value.length > 9)

Comment: Sugumar :  i have case if max digit value max 9 can instert if more or less  than 9 digit not triggred. So don't need to change that :)

Answer (score 0):

add array of exist data:

```
var exists_dataString_arr=[];     //array of exist data

$(window).load(function(){
        $( "#scannerinput" ).focus();
        $('#scannerinput').bind("change paste keyup", function(){
            var barcode = $(this).val();
            var judul = $(this).attr("target-judul");
            var dataString = "judul=" + judul + "&barcode=" + barcode;

            if((this.value.length ==9)&&(exists_dataString_arr.indexOf(ataString)<0)){     //if not in array
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url+"ajax",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        //window.location.href = url;
                        exists_dataString_arr=[];
                    }
                });
                exists_dataString_arr.push(dataString);        //add data in array
                $( "#scannerinput" ).blur(); 
                //console.log(dataString);
            }
        });
    });
```